# Mac 1 TB drive doesn't spin up on PC

Tags: mac, hard-drive

I'm trying to read a 1TB drive (Hitachi hds721010kla330) from a Mac on a PC, but no matter what I do, it doesn't spin up. I tried connecting it through a USB-to_SATA controller, but also on the internal SATA of the PC.

An older Hitachi 20 GB IDE has the same problem; it works fine in the Mac G4, but doesn't spin up connected to USB-to-IDE hardware.

They don't report themselves to BIOS or kernel.

It is not a power supply issue. The adapter for the USB-to-SATA controller had no problems with dozens of drives over the last few years. And, the internal PSU of the PC also didn't work.

I can't seem to find any information about problems of Mac disks on PCs. Do Mac drives normally work on other hardware?

Comment: Does a non-"Mac" drive spin up when connected in the same way to the same cabling? Is the drive configured by the Mac for staggered (firmware/OS controlled) spin-up? I can't imagine that there would be anything about the drive holding Mac data causing these problems; your issue almost certainly lies elsewhere.

Comment: The hardware works on other drives. The staggered spin up I'll look into.

Comment: If it's staggered spinup causing your problems, the hard drive *should* identify itself fine to the BIOS/UEFI, although depending on specifics you might not be able to boot from it.

Comment: It doesn't identify itself to BIOS or Linux kernel. So, that does not bode well. HDparm says the power-on in stand-by feature toggle is VERY DANGEROUS...

Comment: You should [edit] your original post to include any additional information requested in comments, rather than responding with a comment.